# Blank row being added between heading and data

Tags: excel, vba

I am losing my mind, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong here, but each time this macro is run I keep on getting a blank row between the column headers and the actual data. The data that is being returned is correct, but I cannot get see why I am getting an extra line at the top!

Can I have a fresh pair of eyes, please!

Thanks

```
Dim LSearchRow As Long
Dim LCopyToRow As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet
On Error GoTo Err_Execute

For Each wks In Worksheets

LSearchRow = 4
LCopyToRow = 4

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set wksCopyTo = ActiveSheet
wks.Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(3)

While Len(wks.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    If wks.Range("AB" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Yes" And wks.Range("AK" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Yes" And wks.Range("BB" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Y" Then

        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy


        wksCopyTo.Select
        wksCopyTo.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        wksCopyTo.Paste

        'Move counter to next row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
        'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
        wks.Select
    End If
    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
Wend

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select
MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Next wks
    Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
```

Comment: Nothing stands out to me, sorry.  I'd throw some `Debug.Print` calls in there and walk through it.

Answer (score 2):

> > > Can I have a fresh pair of eyes, please!

Maybe because you a missing the worksheetname before `Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select`?

After the code executes this line

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`

The current sheet is the new sheet and hence it will refer to the newly created sheet. And later the `wks.Select` returns the control back to your main sheet.

So change that to

```
wks.Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
```

Also your entire sub can be re-written as (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim LSearchRow As Long, LCopyToRow As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet, wksCopyTo As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        LSearchRow = 4: LCopyToRow = 4

        With wks
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            Set wksCopyTo = ActiveSheet
            .Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(3)

            While Len(Trim(.Range("A" & LSearchRow).Value)) > 0
                If .Range("AB" & LSearchRow).Value = "Yes" And _
                   .Range("AK" & LSearchRow).Value = "Yes" And _
                   .Range("BB" & LSearchRow).Value = "Y" Then

                    .Rows(LSearchRow).Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(LCopyToRow)

                    LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
                End If
                LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
            Wend
        End With

        MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    Next wks

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Comment: No, I don't think so otherwise it wouldn't be copying at all. Anyhow, change the code on the select copy would throw an out of range error

Comment: Which code are you following? your code with the small change that I mentioned or the revised code that i gave?

Answer (score 0):

Siddharth is correct when he says *Maybe because you a missing the worksheetname before ...*

Your code sets `wksCopyTo` to `ActiveSheet`, tests for data on `wks` then selects and copies from `ActiveSheet`.  Later in the while loop it selects `wks` - Thats why only the first row is blank

Change those five lines to

```
wks.Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).copy wksCopyTo.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & Str(LCopyToRow))
```